# using dropbox as a server for my django app

Tags: python, django, dropbox, dropbox-api

I dont know if at all i make any sense, but this popped up in my mind. Can we use the 2gb free hosting of dropbox to put our django app over there and do some hacks to run our app?

Comment: Yes, you **can** do it! check my new answer below.

Comment: @Surya has answered your question below and the answer in the affirmative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12542453/795053. I suggest marking their answer as accepted so that other users find that answer first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point you need to understand is: can you run django without djagno installed? Can django be installed on a usb-drive? Dropbox is but a cloud storage service NOT cloud hosting service. To store you do not require RAM and processors while for hosting you do.

Hence the answer is NO. If you are okay with configuring apache etc. you can go for VPS. If not try some managed servers. If you dont want to spend much and are looking at free hosting solutions for django a few of them are:

kodingen.com

shellmix.com

http://0x2a-dc.com/index.php?name=shop&cat=6

http://www.heliohost.org/home/

http://bitnami.org/cloud

https://www.alwaysdata.com/

more data:
http://freedjangohosting.com/

http://djangohosting.com/

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible.

If you want to use dropbox as the hosting, you can put static pages, meaning just the html files with CSS and javascript because those files can be retrieved by doing a  simple GET request.

Hosting a python code is not possible as it requires server side calculations & dropbox is just for saving files.

See the official wiki for the available hosts. https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts

Answer (score 4):

**Yes its possible!** *[PythonAnywhere.com](http://pythonanywhere.com) offers that!*

What pythonanywhere does is pretty simple. They integrate your dropbox account with their one. When you want to create a Django app, all you got to do is, direct the platform to store the app in your dropbox folder!

Now, you can open your Django app in your PC and edit it (wait for some time to sync)..restart the app, it works! I practically tried.

Tip: There are many cloud platforms which offer great services for free. Openshift, Heroku, Google App Engine are to name a few!

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use DropBox to serve a Django Website, as doing so requires Python code to be run, when DropBox is only for saving & serving files.

You can, however, find free hosting for your Django needs, among which:

[Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/), originally meant for Ruby hosting, but now allows you to do Python hosting. I didn't find it particularly easy to use with Django though.

[ep.io](https://www.ep.io/), Python-specific hosting, but invite-only for the moment - it's possible to get an invite by sending an email, explaining your project & your needs though. Offers you free SSL on *.ep.io, which is pretty nice, and they've got great service.

[Dotcloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/), not platform specific, but my personal favorite. It's pretty easy to get started, and the CLI allows you to do a lot (but the downside is that you need it a lot too). If you're not afraid of CLI, it's great.

Answer (score 1):

Being said its not possible from dropbox to do that you can use very simple cloud hosting as told ahead,
I might be late for answer but you can get free cloud hosting from Linux Fedora company called RedHat. Their cloud product is available for free which supports django hosting. I tried it my own
[Openshift Free Cloud Hosting](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Thomas posted, some other options for free django hosting:

1. Amazon Compute Instance ([free for one year](http://aws.amazon.com/free/), free sign up).
2. Google App Engine ([free limits](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html),[django howto](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html)).
3. OpenShift ([django howto](https://github.com/openshift/django-example)).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i went through the documentation of django howto. there inside the introduction i found "....Engine, you can stop reading this article." i went to their site and saw that post november 24 the developers wont be working for it. one probable reason i think is appengine is not that big a success as was expected(correct me if i am wrong). i was hence confused as to what to use. How do you compare AWS with appengine? What are the reviews of OpenShift?

Comment: AWS = Your own computer, do what you want.
App Engine = Python is first class citizen, lots of active Python support, challenge is their storage engine.
OpenShift = Promising; good if you use MongoDB as they have great support for it. Built on Jboss, which is very reliable.

Comment: i chose python because of django(most would have gone the other way), please modify your comments on GAE with respect to my concerns. Effort would be appreciated. Thanks.